# Redirect request for specific URL to other URL

Tags: google-chrome, url, desktop-customization, web-application, google-hangouts

I use the Google Hangouts Webapp (https://hangouts.google.com, not the extension) in Chrome on Windows 10. I also have a local Linux webdev machine that also runs a litely-configured DNSMasq instance for some bare-minimum DNS stuff.

I like Hangouts for phone calls and messages, however, I find the sound for incoming messages to be *very* annoying. I don't want to disable notifications or mute them, instead I'd like to replace the sound with something a bit more to my liking.

Watching property inspector, I've isolated the sound to the following address:
`https://ssl.gstatic.com/chat/sounds/incoming_message_eb39ce414e3ffba41a8e173581dc7248.mp3`

I'm hosting my preferred sound as a mp3 file on a local VM, such as `https://webdevmachine.test/incoming.mp3`

Is there any way to redirect a JavaScript request to a *specific* external URL to a custom one of my choosing?

### Similar question answers/failed solutions:

- I've tried a couple Chrome extensions that match and redirect URLs via RegEx, but all of them only seem to work for the URL bar and not from a page's JS requests, which the Hangouts webapp is presumably using to get the resources.
- Editing my hosts file seems to be out, as I would only be able to use a whole IP/domain and I don't want to mirror/keep track of every resource Google has hosted at that domain.
- It's my understanding that DNSMasq is too low level, as it doesn't concern itself with anything beyond resolving the domain to an IP.
- AdBlock would block the resource, which is unacceptable.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after a couple more days of research and trial and error, I found the ["Requestly"](https://requestly.io) Chrome extension that allows filtering/modifying all HTTP requests.

Set up a rule to match the resources I wanted to replace and pointed them elsewhere. Worked perfectly.